# Why does establishing a JDBC connection freeze the UI thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I am using the following code to open connection to SQL database using JDBC

```
    Runnable getConn = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                tracking = true;
                activity.run();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread connection = new Thread(getConn);
    connection.run();
```

it works but it freezes UI thread till connection is opened. Any ideas on how to move this to separate thread so it wont stop UI thread? I was doing this on android using `asyncTask` but I dont know how to do it in Java.

Comment: `connection.start()`?

Comment: thanks it works... post it as solution and I will accept it

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this question.  The OP gave just enough code and and a question.  Not to mention the down voter didn't bother to explain why.  Some people are just frustrating.

Comment: @horin Posted it as an answer. I seem to have missed your comment (possibly because you did not address it to me by using @CKing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You need to change the `connection.run()` statement to `connection.start()`.

**Long answer**

Every Java program begins it's execution with the *main* thread. In other words, when you run a Java program that has a `main` method (e.g java MyProgram), a new execution stack is created with the `main` method at the bottom of this stack.

If a program creates a `Thread` instance in the `main` method and calls the `start` method on the thread instance, a new execution stack will be created with the `run` method at the bottom of the stack. You will now have two execution stacks. One with the `main` method at the bottom of the stack and the other with the `run` method at the bottom of the stack. These two stacks can continue their execution in parallel.

On the other hand, If you call `run` on a thread instance in the `main` method instead, it will simply be called in the same execution stack as the `main` method. A new execution stack will not be created. Therefore, calling `run` on a thread instance is as good as calling any other method on any other object and has no special meaning.